# C# Организация данных подмодулей

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой организации данных.

Есть приложение которое динамически подтягивает DLL модули. Внутри каждого модуля есть есть функционал разбитый по Namespace и независим друг от друга, но кроме данных. Не могу понять как организовать коммуникацию функционала, так как каждый подмодуль является классом под интерфейс.

Есть два способа хранения информации, это расширить интерфейс для подмодуля, в который можно прокинуть данные, либо добавить SQLite базу данных.

Вопрос в том, что лучше использовать, и может есть более лучшие способы хранения информации? файлы не предлагать, так как клиент-серверное приложение и там мусора нехватало.

Comment: Модули наверное не должны зависеть друг от друга. То есть обмен данными между модулями должен быть через центральное приложение.

Comment: Как таковое есть, просто прокидывать в интерфейс объекты с ссылками данных, или воспользоваться микро БД для этого, вот в этом вопрос. Модули независимы, только есть пересекающиеся данные, используемые в нескольких, но они достаточно большие и их хранение в каждой займет достаточно большое количество ОЗУ

Comment: Есть принципы SOLID, в частности SRP. Поизучайте, возможно эта концепция проектирования содержит ответы на ваши вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую с ними покопаться, сталкивался с ними, но не вникал.